# Git - cannot push the first commit

Tags: git, github

Well this problem is very strange.
I created a new repository on Bitbucket and Github too.

For example, the Github gives this information:

```
git init
git add --all
git commit -m "Initial commit."
git remote add origin https://github.com/[myusername]/[myreponame].git
git push -u origin master
```

Well ok, I run the `git init` the `add`, `commit` and `remote add` commands. But when I try to execute the last command: `git push -u origin master`. I get this ***** error always:

```
git push -u origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://[the valid - existing address]'
```

Nice... of course it does not find nothing, because this is the first commit, but I cannot checkin my first commit... What can I do? (maybe switch to svn?)

**git status** show this:

```
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:

(use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

new file: .bowerrc
new file: .gitignore
//etc
```

Comment: Can you check if you are actually on the master branch locally? Execute `git status` to get the branch name. Also, which Git version do you have? I just tried the same here and it works perfectly.

Comment: No, I am not on the master branch locally, because this is my first commit in the repo.

Comment: Are you sure there is a commit existing. This might happen if try adding and then directly pushing without committing. 
Also can paste the result for 

    git show-ref 
to see what refs do you have
Is there refs/heads/master?

Comment: updated the question. "git show-ref" shows nothing. But is this natural cause there werenot any commit, cause this wants to be the first :D

Comment: Okay, your earlier comment was a bit misleading, but it's understandable since it's a bit confusing. You are on branch master locally, even though branch master hasn't really been created yet. Did the `git add` or `git commit` commands report any errors?

Comment: No, the commands did not report any errors :(

Comment: What are the exact commands you ran? It obviously won't be just `git add README.md`, since that wouldn't have staged your `.bowerrc`, `.gitignore`, etc.

Comment: I updated the commands.

Comment: Your `git status` shows that you have not yet made the first commit.  What happened when you ran the `git commit -m "Initial commit."`?

Comment: This is interesting nothing happen, the `git commit` command does not show the common message: `create mode ..... `. I miss this.

Answer (score 1):

> Nice... of course it does not find nothing, because this is the first commit, but I cannot check in my first commit... What can I do? (maybe switch to svn?)
>
> #### `git status show this:`
>
> ```
> On branch master
>
> Initial commit
> Changes to be committed:
> (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
>
> new file: .bowerrc
> new file: .gitignore
> //etc
> ```

If git status display the content - **you don't** have commit yet.

To verify is you have a commit or not do

```
git log
```

If there is an commit you will see it.

Second thing that you should do is use the

```
git add .

# do this instead of you git add --all (for the first commit)
```

On your ***first commit***

> ***`-A / --all / --no-ignore-removal`***
>
> Update the index not only where the working tree has a file matching  but also **where the index already has an entry**.
>
> **This adds, modifies, and removes index entries to match the working tree.**
>
> If no  is given when -A option is used, all files in the entire working tree are updated (old versions of Git used to limit the update to the current directory and its subdirectories).

---

I followed the same path you did:

[image]